# Resize Google Compute Cloud boot disk to 4TB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to resize the boot disk of a Google Compute cloud instance to 4TB.

I'm following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_partitions), but the disk appears to only go up to 2TB:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             45G     0   45G   0% /dev
tmpfs           8.9G  8.6M  8.9G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       2.0T   96G  1.9T   5% /
tmpfs            45G     0   45G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            45G     0   45G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           8.9G     0  8.9G   0% /run/user/1001

$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   4T  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   2T  0 part /

$ sudo growpart /dev/sda 1
NOCHANGE: partition 1 could only be grown by 1 [fudge=2048]

$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 536870655 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

$ df -h /dev/sda1 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       2.0T   96G  1.9T   5% /
```

So at the end the /dev/sda1 disk is only 2TB. Is 2TB an upper limit? Is there a way to increase it? My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, boot disks are limited to 2TB according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_partitions):

> Note: Boot disks use MBR partitions, which are limited to 2 TB in size. Do not resize boot disks beyond 2 TB.

Unfortunately I missed this detail when resizing the disk.